# Migrating from Cisco ASA 5508 to Cisco Meraki Firewall Appliance at small office

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

At a small remote office my boss decided to buy a Meraki Firewall device with Wireless to replace an old Cisco ASA.  The setup looks pretty straight forward.  We have 5 public IP addresses for an e-mail server, 2 web servers, our ASA outside interface and the last one is used for PAT on the ASA.

In the Meraki dashboard it was easy to set up 1:1 NAT for our servers and I have the outside interface public IP configured but where do I conigure the PAT internet address that all of our internal clients use to get on the internet?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: The 5508 is not "old", but the brand new, current generation replacement for the 5505. One call/email to Meraki would answer your question. Also, there are plenty of webinars and demos of how to manage things through their cloud dashboard.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the section named 1:Many NAT on this page https://docs.meraki.com/display/MX/Firewall+settings.

The relevant portion is summarized here.

1. Click the button labled **Add 1:Many IP**
2. Enter the Public IP address and Uplink values

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into several situations similar to this and engaged Meraki support to confirm.

1:Many NAT only allows you to specify a WAN IP address to have ports forwarded to multiple internal hosts.

1:1 NAT only links 1 WAN IP to 1 LAN IP

Port Forwarding is only tied to the external IP of the Meraki device itself

That said those are your only options within Meraki, you cannot PAT an entire subnet to a different WAN IP Address.  If this is required you will need to either reconfigure your internal network to make the Meraki work or get another ASA.